# Why are cloud-init processes running long after server creation?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud-init

I'm spinning up a new Ubuntu 18.04 cloud server and using a `cloud-init` to install docker.  I can see that the `cloud-init` process runs and apparently completes fine, by inspecting the `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` file.  But I'm finding that several `cloud-init` processes are still running long after this, and using up CPU:

[image]

These `cloud-init` processes appears on the `top` list every 30 seconds or so, then drop off, then back again.  Any way to diagnose this further... why is `cloud-init` running at all after it has apparently finished, and why so many processes?

I'm also seeing a CPU trace which has regular peaks which seem to follow the same pattern:

[image]

Looking at `/var/log/cloud-init.log`, I see that it goes crazy every 30 seconds or so, outputting the following, with a small number of lines repeated over and over again:

```
2021-11-13 19:21:25,927 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug-hook called with the following arguments: {hotplug_action: query, subsystem: net, udevaction: None, devpath: None}
2021-11-13 19:21:25,928 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:25,928 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Fetching datasource
2021-11-13 19:21:25,928 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [trust]
2021-11-13 19:21:25,928 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:25,928 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18131 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl
2021-11-13 19:21:25,931 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 9 bytes from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - stages.py[DEBUG]: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook/check-cache: SUCCESS: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug not supported for event of type net
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook: SUCCESS: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Exiting hotplug handler
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 17 bytes from /proc/uptime
2021-11-13 19:21:25,932 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'hotplug-hook' took 0.058 seconds (0.06)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,035 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug-hook called with the following arguments: {hotplug_action: query, subsystem: net, udevaction: None, devpath: None}
2021-11-13 19:21:26,035 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:26,035 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Fetching datasource
2021-11-13 19:21:26,035 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [trust]
2021-11-13 19:21:26,036 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,036 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18131 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl
2021-11-13 19:21:26,039 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,039 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 9 bytes from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id
2021-11-13 19:21:26,039 - stages.py[DEBUG]: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:26,039 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook/check-cache: SUCCESS: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:26,039 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug not supported for event of type net
2021-11-13 19:21:26,040 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook: SUCCESS: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:26,040 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Exiting hotplug handler
2021-11-13 19:21:26,040 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,040 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 17 bytes from /proc/uptime
2021-11-13 19:21:26,040 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'hotplug-hook' took 0.054 seconds (0.06)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,054 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug-hook called with the following arguments: {hotplug_action: query, subsystem: net, udevaction: None, devpath: None}
2021-11-13 19:21:26,054 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:26,054 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Fetching datasource
2021-11-13 19:21:26,054 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: hotplug-hook/check-cache: attempting to read from cache [trust]
2021-11-13 19:21:26,055 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,055 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 18131 bytes from /var/lib/cloud/instance/obj.pkl
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 9 bytes from /run/cloud-init/.instance-id
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - stages.py[DEBUG]: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook/check-cache: SUCCESS: restored from cache with run check: DataSourceHetzner
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: hotplug not supported for event of type net
2021-11-13 19:21:26,058 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: hotplug-hook: SUCCESS: Handle reconfiguration on hotplug events
2021-11-13 19:21:26,059 - hotplug_hook.py[DEBUG]: Exiting hotplug handler
2021-11-13 19:21:26,059 - util.py[DEBUG]: Reading from /proc/uptime (quiet=False)
2021-11-13 19:21:26,059 - util.py[DEBUG]: Read 17 bytes from /proc/uptime
2021-11-13 19:21:26,059 - util.py[DEBUG]: cloud-init mode 'hotplug-hook' took 0.057 seconds (0.05)
```

Answer (score 2):

From a helpful chat over on the #cloud-init IRC channel, apparently this relates to a problem with cloud-init version 21.3 that is fixed in 21.4, which will be released in a few days.

Until then, a fix is:

```
rm -f /lib/udev/rules.d/10-cloud-init-hook-hotplug.rules
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Comment: For further context here is a link to the bug [on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1946003) and the PR [on github](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/pull/1069).